# How to change bootstrap navigation menu colors?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

I want to change the color of the "Home" "Spin" "Social Media" but no clue how. I spent a few days on figuring out how to change the navigation background but have no clue on the color because I only want to change the grey to white and change the hover color as well. I can change the color to white but then the hover color would be ignored. Is there an intended way to do this?

Here is how I changed the navigation background color.

```
.navbar-inverse {
    background-color:#66ccff;
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

incase it helps :D

Comment: typically if you use chrome, FF, or IE's "inspect element" you can narrow down what to target in your css much faster than days!

Comment: Most downvotes come from lack of applicable code. The more code provided the better. You can also create a jsFiddle which is really helpful.

Comment: I totally agree with the more code you give the better. But most people just downvote and leave so new people won't know why their answer got downvoted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a relatively comprehensive breakdown of the navigation components and often changed properties. I would suggest using a custom class in your main navbar div (`navbar-custom` is used for this example) to avoid changing the base CSS directly.

```css
/***Navbar Background Color, Border Removed ,Border Radius Sqaure***/

.navbar.navbar-custom {
  background: #66ccff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0;
}
/***Link Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #f00;
}
/***Link Color Hover Statr***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
  color: #ff0;
}
/***Link Background and Color Active State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
  background: #DBF022;
  color: #66ccff;
}
/***Navbar Brand Link Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand {
  color: #f00;
}
/***Navbar Brand Link Color Hover State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #ff0;
}
/***Dropdown Background Active State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .nav li.dropdown.open > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar.navbar-custom .nav li.dropdown.active > .dropdown-toggle,
.navbar.navbar-custom .nav li.dropdown.open.active > .dropdown-toggle {
  background: #DBF022;
  color: #f00;
}
/***Dropdown-menu Background Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu {
  background: #66ccff;
  border: none;
}
/***Dropdown-menu Color***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a {
  color: #f00;
}
/***Dropdown-menu Color Hover and Focus State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
  color: #ff0;
  background: #f00;
}
/***Toggle Button***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle {
  border-color: #f00;
}
/***Toggle Button Hover and Focus State***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-header .navbar-toggle:focus {
  background: #f00;
  border: #f00;
}
/***Collapse Borders***/

.navbar.navbar-custom .navbar-collapse {
  border: none;
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    color: #f00;
  }
  /***Dropdown-menu Color Hover and Focus State***/
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
  .navbar.navbar-custom li.dropdown .dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ff0;
    background: #f00;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-custom">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false"> <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>

      </button> <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>

    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a>

        </li>
        <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks for your indepth answer!

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .nav > li > a
```

that is the target you are seeking!

Answer (score 0):

to customize use the below selectors...

(note, you won't need `!important` if your customizations are loaded after the bootstrap css, ie your `<link href="..my-customizations.css" />` loaded after `<link href="...cdn...bootstrap.min.css" />`)

```css
/* links */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: red!important;
}

/* active, focus or hover links */
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, 
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
  color: red!important;
}
```

[<kbd>jsfiddle example</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/yaq9cw18/1)

Comment: So I see that for the active, focus, or hover links, you put the color red. However, when I hover over it in the jsfiddle you provided, when I hover over the words, I got white.

Comment: Can't accept your answer atm because the hover doesn't work.