# How to make all the buttons active in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
  <p>The .navbar-right class is used to right-align navigation bar buttons.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

If you run the code you can notice all the buttons (e.g. WebsiteName, Page1,2,3, signup and login) are all grey. Except HOME. How can I deactivate the grey buttons?

Comment: when u say deactivate, do u mean to make them not clickable?

Comment: @HieuLe: No I still want them clickable. But I want them to have 'active color' (i.e. white).

Comment: Just add class="active" to their li tags

Comment: @HieuLe: I tried. Didn't work. And the `navbar-brand` I also want them to have white color.

Comment: The *Home* button has the `active` class applied to it. The rest are not disabled, the grey style is just suggestive that those links are not associated with the active page. If you want to change the style, override the font colour in your own CSS file.

Comment: This post may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706944/how-to-change-bootstrap-navigation-menu-colors/32708282#32708282

Answer (score 2):

See below.

But this is not the best case to go. Better to do global changes in CSS.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
  
<div class="container">
  <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
  <p>The .navbar-right class is used to right-align navigation bar buttons.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to override the default gray color to white. The `active` state you are referring to is irrelevant here as it is a functionality rather than presentation. The changes need to be done to the CSS.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #fff;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 2</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Page 3</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Right Aligned Navbar</h3>
    <p>The .navbar-right class is used to right-align navigation bar buttons.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: dont forget to change your :hover and :fucus psuedo classes if you are changing the default color to white, if you want some distinction when hovering and clicking :)