# How to customize bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, intellij-idea

I'm trying to make a change to the text color on my navbar but it doesn't to work. I'm using bootstrap locally not from cdn.

Here is a screen shot of my code:[image]

[image]

Comment: you need to overwrite the styles defined in boostrap.css. Try `navbar{color:white!important;}`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change bootstrap navigation menu colors?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32706944/how-to-change-bootstrap-navigation-menu-colors)

Comment: I should put the: !important; : behind the color tag

Comment: I tried using !important and it didn't work. I wondering if I should try to use an id on it?

Comment: Please post your codes here and not just a screenshot of your codes Taylor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want to change the anchor within the `navbar-nav` wrapper of your navbar class, you should specify that in your css too like this:

```
.navbar-nav li a {
    color:white !important;
}
```

Demo jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/65sf2f66/69/

Answer (score 1):

You should override bootstrap using the "!important" keyword..

Example:

```
.navbar {
color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried this and this worked. Thank you.